# @DataProvider in testng at class level

Tags: java, testng

I try to run `@Test` method, but define `@Test` at class level with `dataProvider` attribute and also mention method as a `@Test`, please take look on below code for more idea

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test(dataProvider="Data")
public class TestAtClassLevel{

    @Test
    public void testCase(String value) {
        System.out.println("Test case");
    }

    @DataProvider(name="Data")
    public Object[][] dataProvider(){
        String value[][]=new String[2][1];
        value[0][0]="FirstValue";
        value[1][0]="SecondValue";
        return value;
    }
}
```

I try to run the above code but I get the below exception:

```
[Utils] [ERROR] [Error] org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [testCase] with [class java.lang.String].
```

I am able to run the above code after remove `@Test` from method-level

Why am I getting an exception even if I declare data provider name at class level?

Comment: how do you provide a value for `String value` variable at runtime? https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Test.html#:~:text=The%20Test%20annotation%20tells%20JUnit,by%20JUnit%20as%20a%20failure.

Comment: @JudeNiroshan The question is more specific to testNG than junit.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted the `testCase` method to get data from the data provider then mention that against the test method itself instead of using it at the class level. Or remove the `@Test` against the method without removing the annotation at class level, so that the method level annotation do not override the class level configuration.

```java
@Test(dataProvider="Data")
public void testCase(String value) {
    System.out.println("Test case");
}
```

Mentioning `dataProviderClass` is useful at the class level, when the data providers are defined in a different class and this property would indicate testng to look for data providers in the mentioned class. Still, you need to mention the specific data provider name at the method level itself.

Comment: Thank gautham for reply but if not add @Test to method level and run the above code then testng use dataprovider which will mention in class level

Comment: @ankushpawar once you put a `@Test` at the method level, it would override the class level `@Test`

Comment: @ankushpawar If you have the annotation at the class level and you do not have any specific overriding required at the method level, then no need to annotate that method with `@Test`

Comment: ok,please clear me if my understanding is wrong,here i understand that if add same attribute to class level as well as method level then TestNG use both the values mention in class level and method level for example if we add groups attribute with value as "Data" in class level and add group="Test" then corresponding method should be belongs to both cases

Comment: but attributes which accept onlt one value like enable and we menton enabled=true at class level and enabled=false then testng override the value mention in method level

Comment: @ankushpawar Yes i think this could be a bug as well. Have you tried with the latest version of `testNG` ? But anyway I recommend the use of dataProvider property at the method level because the data required for a test case should be mentioned along with the method itself. I believe that is more readable.

Comment: i used the TestNG version 6.14.3,thank you for help

Comment: @ankushpawar if the issue is present in the latest version as well, then it would be good if you could mention it here -> https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues

Comment: @ankushpawar Also, If you are raising a bug in the above github repo, then please update the question with the link to that issue.

Comment: This issue is not reflect in TestNg version 7.4.0,thank you